# Nginx no redirect rewrite

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Hi i have a problem with nginx rewrite.
I can not find a rule to rewrite without making a http redirect (301)

`http://slug-site-1.example.com?param=1..` -> `http://example.com/multysite/slug-site-1?param=1..`

My nginx rewrite is

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name serverName;
 location / {
  rewrite ^/$ myHttpUrl/multySite/slug-site-1 last;
 }
}
```

Comment: You must use proxy module http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Comment: But probably you want something different.

Comment: Yea I'd say a `proxy_pass` would do it, but if both sites are on the same device you can switch to the other root and do a rewrite, is that what you want to do ?

Comment: Yes is a unique site but my rule make a redirect slug-sit-1.example.com to example.com/../slug-site1.